# MySql ODBC 5.3 (a) Driver optional feature not supported while inserting from trigger

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linked-server

I have one MySQL Server and SQL Server 2016 and have access the MySQL Database objects in SQL Server using a linked server. When executing the `OPENQUERY` of DML it was working good but when executing those query's from trigger its show's the following message

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "linkserverName" returned message
> [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver] Optional feature not supported.

Comment: Does `exec (@query) at LinkedServerName` work?